# Why provide two get functions

Tags: c++, boost

```
class T
{};

class AccessT
{
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<const T> getT() const {return m_T;}
    boost::shared_ptr<T>       getT()       {return m_T;}

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<T> m_T;
};
```

Question> I saw lots of similar codes as above in the legacy project.
I really don't understand the point of doing so.
Why not just simply provide the following instead:

```
class T
{};

class AccessTModified
{
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<T> getT() const { return m_T; }

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<T> m_T;
};
```

The initial argument may be that `boost::shared_ptr<const T> getT() const` will not let const object modifies the T by accident. If that is the case, is it a practice that all such functions should provide two versions? To me, I feel very tedious!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct:  the purpose of `boost::shared_ptr<const T> getT() const` is to ensure that `const` objects can't modify the T by accident.

In C++, this is known as *const correctness* and is usually considered to be good C++ design.  As you said, it often results in getters having two versions (a `const` and a non-`const` version).  It can be initially tedious (although it's not bad once you get used to it), but the results can be quite useful.  Const correctness lets you declare functions like

```
void DoSomething(const AccessT& item);
```

that promise not to modify `item` so that the compiler throws an error if `DoSomething` does anything that's declared as possibly modifying `item`.

Although const correctness is usually considered to be good C++ design, some developers decide that the overhead of having to declare const and non-const versions of some functions to be more trouble than it's worth.

The C++ FAQ has [a whole section](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html) on const correctness, if you're interested in more information.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is common when the need for an accessor class is felt, but the author doesn't want to go the whole way of defining `AccessT` and `AccessTconst` for access and constant access. The hack you see is the less tedious way of making constant and non-constant access possible through constant and non-constant accessors.

The advantage of this pattern is an easy implementation, the disadvantage is that you mingle the concepts of "const pointer" and "pointer to const". If an AccessT provides a `setT` member, confusion about const-ness will ensue.

You can contrast this access pattern with the `const_` pattern shown e.g. by iterators, which come as `const_iterator` and `iterator` and allow all four combinations of changeable iterator and changeable iterated.